# Handle concurrency in the user interface when a data record is deleted/updated

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I would like to know how should I handle the scenarios in the user interface when:

1.) A user deletes a data record which got already deleted by another user

When the data record is already deleted it won`t be deleted anymore and with something like "Delete From Table Where Id = @IdToDelete" nothing bad should happen.

But should I not tell my user instead:"Sorry we could not delete the data record because it got already deleted by user xyz" ??

2.) A user updates a data record which got already modified by another user?
Should I show for all my update() scenarios a window to the user with the new value and old value and let him choose or decide finally what will win ?

Answer (score 0):

1) Generally, I wouldn't expect any message to be displayed to the user here since functionally what they asked to be done was done.

2) This is where you often get a warning about trying to update a modified record displayed to the user.  How you display that warning depends a lot on your user requirements and how complicated a warning you want to display.  The simplest solution is to warn them and ask them to refresh their local copy of the record, but this usually means that they need to re-do their changes which is a frustration point for users.  Showing them the conflicts would be a nicer user experience, but could be a bit more complicated especially for large records.

Comment: I rephrase my question 2) Should I show an old/new value Window for ALL my update-statements because for everyone there could be a dirty field already changed by another user.

Answer (score 0):

1) Where does the information would come from? If you don't log who deleted what record then the database would not tell you this information.

2) It depends on your app - there are cases where "the last wins" strategy is OK and there are cases when it is not OK. You decide what you need/want to do if there are conflicts

Comment: 1) The ExecuteNonQuery (delete) has a return parameter which is the affected Records which can be checked easily...